React Native - Failed to install the app on the device
I have a react native app, and I try to run the command adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 & set NODE_ENV=development & react-native run-android --list-devices --verbose --mode=DevDebug
I get, after a really long time to build ( like, 10 minutes build time ), the following error :

The device I try to install the app in is my phone, connected via Wifi to Android Studio.
I have no idea why it does that, I am a noob at RN, so I don't know what further infos you could need. I already tryied the others solutions in similar questions, but nothing is quite the same problem.
When I run the command set NODE_ENV=development & react-native start, I have a different error because of the flavor variant, the --mode=DevDebug that is in my previous command.
Thanks in advance !
